# Access 2010 Form Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I created a form with unbound fields.  These fields are used in a multi field query.  In the query on the first line i used `Like "*" & [Forms]![frmMemberDetailLookup]![txtID] & "*" or IS NULL`

But when i went back to edit the query, i have hundred lines of the criteria in the "or" rows - `Like "*" & [Forms]![frmMemberDetailLookup]![txtID] & "*"`.  Then `[frmMemberDetailLookup]![txtID]` appearing as a field and `Is Null` in the criteria and "or" rows.  Why is Access doing this?  It makes it impossible to modify the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you use a lookup field.

Refrain from this "smart" feature as it will only cause you troubles - as you've already seen.